# MongoDB query to filter sub documents from nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given this embedded document structure :

```
organisation
  district
    property
      installation 
        installation_type
```

I wish to retrieve only the properties where installation_type = e.g. 'Gas boiler'

I've tried :

```
db.organisation.find({ "district.property.installation.installation_type": { $all: ['Gas boiler'] }})
```

but this returns the entire document for any **organisation** with a gas boiler. This means I also get properties that don't have Gas boilers. I want a list of **only properties** with 'Gas boilers'

**Example doc :**

```
db.organisation.insert({
  _id: 'Organsiation 1',
  district: [
  {
    _id: 'District 1',
    property: [
      {
        _id: 'Property 1',
        address_line_1: 'Adress 1',
        installation: [
          {
            _id: 'HS01',
            installation_type: 'Gas boiler',
            component: [
              {
                _id: 'P01',
                component_type: 'Circulation pump',
              },
              {
                _id: 'EXP01',
                component_type: 'Expansion tank',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            _id: 'HW01',
            installation_type: 'Electric water heater',
            component: [
              {
                _id: 'P01',
                component_type: 'Circulation pump',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            _id: 'V01',
            installation_type: 'Ventilation',
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 'District 2',
    property: [
      {
        _id: 'Property 2',
        address_line_1: 'Adress 2',
        installation: [
          {
            _id: 'HS01',
            installation_type: 'Geo Heat Pump',
          },
          {
            _id: 'HS02',
            installation_type: 'Gas boiler',
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        _id: 'Property 3',
        installation: [
          {
            _id: 'HS01',
            installation_type: 'Gas boiler',
          } 
        ]
      },
    ],
  }
]
})
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you provide us with sample document !!

Comment: Done! - see question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this multiple nested arrays, You either do `$unwind` or use filters like below, but using `$unwind` will explode collection with large no.of docs, So doing this should work as it should be running `$addFields` on doc size lesser than original collection size :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** This match can be optional if dealing with data set of small size, else it can help a lot to filter docs which has at-least 'Gas boiler' */
    {
      $match: {
        "district.property.installation.installation_type": "Gas boiler"
      }
    },
    /** Iterate over each array till property array but on installation use filter to filter only object matches with required criteria,
     *  Use mergeObjects to merge actual object with returned array, to preserve other fields apart from `property` & `installation` */
    {
      $addFields: {
        district: {
          $map: {
            input: "$district",
            as: "d",
            in: {
              $mergeObjects: [
                "$$d",
                {
                  property: {
                    $map: {
                      input: "$$d.property",
                      as: "p",
                      in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                          "$$p",
                          {
                            installation: {
                              $filter: {
                                input: "$$p.installation",
                                cond: {
                                  $eq: [
                                    "$$this.installation_type",
                                    "Gas boiler"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iD_2VE4EGbU)

Comment: Thankyou @whoami - your time on this is much appreciated. I shall read and digest :)